# Mermaid entity relation diagram

Tags: mermaid

I have read mermaid styling documentation section:
https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/entityRelationshipDiagram?id=styling

Now, I can't figure out how to apply any styles for the ER diagram.There are no any examples or general info about styling.

Does any body have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The important part of the documentation is "Config options" section. this mean the styles should be placed accordinly.
Mermaid config could be placed into `mermaid.initialize()` or inline on the first line of your digram with `%%{init: { }}%% expression`. You can see details here https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/./directives.

example for ER diagram styling:

```
%%{init: {'themeCSS': '.er.attributeBoxEven { fill: #f2f2f2; }' }}%%
```